# iOS application launch after updating to Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: xcode, ios7

I upgraded my mac OS to mavericks and also my Xcode 4.6 to Xcode 5.1.1.
I tried to launch my iOS app which was originally built on iOS 6 in the iOS 7.1 simulator.
I get the login page as intended but as soon as the login page is displayed I get an error in the main method exactly at the below line and the execution stops there. The description says "signal SIGKILL". I am not able to figure out a fix for this as all the app delegates call back methods are called fine and there seems to be no issues with the application code. Can anyone please let me know what could be the problem here.

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CommVotesAppDelegate class]));
```

Comment: Put breakpoint, and find which line is causing the issue.

Comment: I already did breakpoints. After calling applicationDidBecomeActive method it goes to the main and throws "signal SIGKILL". Is there something am missing ?